# How to insert a pdf page as a front cover?

Tags: bookcover

I have to insert a pdf page as a front cover for my thesis. How could I do it? This a mwe:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that it works when I insert: \usepackage{pdfpages}  and \includepdf[pages=1]{pt.pdf}

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Integrating_the_title_page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments and, since no one wrote an answer,
I made this answer a **community wiki** answer.
The original answer was by the OP @domi:

Using [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=1]{pt.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to add an empty page after the cover (in case of a twosided document), use `pages={1,{}}`.